# Best way to create a bootable Windows USB from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, boot, bootable-media

I am trying to create a bootable Windows installation USB from Ubuntu, and can't seem to find anything on doing this, even after googling it. I have tried "Startup Disk Creator" but I believe that is only valid for Ubuntu as when I try and select my Windows7.iso, it does not do anything or even recognize it as being selected. What is the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try WinUSB: http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/winusb-create-bootable-windows-installer-usb-in-ubuntu-linux/

> WinUSB is an Ubuntu application for creating a Windows USB installer
>   for Windows Vista and Windows 7. Like other applications that enable
>   creating installer USBs, you can create a bootable (installation) USB
>   from an ISO disc image or a DVD. While other tools like Unetbootin can
>   perform similar tasks, however, WinUSB is much simpler than other
>   competitors, and delivers a two-click solution for creating a Windows
>   installer USB. This may be a blessing for users who may require
>   creating a USB installer for Windows for dual booting it with Ubuntu
>   or other Linux distributions. Similarly, you might require installing
>   Windows on another system, but do not have Windows installed on a
>   computer to utilize tools such as the Windows 7 USB DVD Tool.